# Preventing tic labels from resizing graph in gnuplot

Tags: resize, gnuplot, axes, autosize

I'm trying to make a general plot where I don't know the range.  Sometimes there will be more zero's or a "-" on the tic marks, which causes the graph area to contract.  I would prefer the tic labels just extend farther to the left preserving the graph size.  This helps with alignment which is a crucial part of these plots.

Does anyone have an idea about how to do this? My searches haven't revealed anything yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `set lmargin` to set a fixed left margin. With e.g. `set lmargin 10` you fix the left margin to 10 character widths:

```
set multiplot layout 2,1
set lmargin 10    
set xrange [0:10]
plot x

set xrange[0:100000]
plot x
unset multiplot
```

[image]

Of course, you must still find an appropriate setting for the left margin size.

As another point, also the label position depends on the ticlabel length.

```
set multiplot layout 2,1
set lmargin 10
set ylabel 'ylabel'

set xrange [0:10]
plot x

set xrange[0:100000]
plot x
unset multiplot
```

[image]

So you would need to change the ylabel position with the `offset` parameter. To have it more general, you can put the ylabel with a usual `set label` command to have it fixed independent of the margin settings:

```
set multiplot layout 2,1
set lmargin 10
set label 1 'manual label' at screen 0.03,graph 0.5 center rotate by 90

set xrange [0:10]
plot x

set xrange[0:100000]
plot x
unset multiplot
```

[image]

Comment: horribly late but better than never.  Thanks for the reply, this solved my issue entirely.