# How to fix the plot in GNUplot?

Tags: linux, bash, plot, gnuplot

I have to plot graphs for different sets of values. For each set of values, the yrange and y2range differs and because of that the plot compresses or expands horizontally (according to the ytics and y2tics). Is there any way by which I can disable horizontal autoscaling of the plot so that the plot points have the same relative position(x pixel, horizontal) in all the graphs?

In other words, I have to set the plot within a rectangle whose dimensions shouldn't change or get scaled with the data of ytics and y2tics.

Comment: post your current code

Comment: doesn't plot range help?

Comment: Use `set lmargin` and `set rmargin`, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27280459/2604213 for an example using only `lmargin`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww I'm sorry that it didn't feel like that. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I was able to resolve it by just using lmargin and rmargin as @Christoph has told here. By fixing it the plot doesn't get squeezed up horizontally respective to the ytics and y2tics.